# Ubuntu14.04LTS desktop app launcher for node? - Desktop Entry

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

**This is not a duplicated question. The link suggested is for Shell Script, and I can launch node app via shell script doing normaly just 'node app', but for .desktop file, it does not work. So the answer linked never solve my problem,** and what is the point to try to close the question suggesting to use an unsatisfied answer.

I simply try to exec `node app` from the current directory where .desktop file exists.
I do as follows, but for unknown reason, it does not work.
Surely, when I do `node app` on the directory, the node app launches as expected.
Any idea? Thanks.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=JS Bin
Comment=JS Bin Offline REPL
Exec=node '"$(dirname "$1")"/app'
Icon=/home/ken/Google Drive/js-bin/code.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Exec=node '/home/ken/Google Drive/js-bin/app.js'

would be the same result.

Just in case, I don't have to re-login to make this work, correct?

Comment: Is `node '/home/ken/Google Drive/js-bin/app.js'` work in your terminal?

Comment: @Kash This is not duplicated question. The link you suggested is for Shell Script, and I can launch node app via shell script doing normaly just 'node app', but for .desktop file, it does not work. So the answer you linked never solve my problem, and what is the point to try to close the question suggesting to use an unsatisfied answer.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

for node.js program, we should be careful for the path.

I have to do like

```
var app1 = proc.spawn(atom, [__dirname + '/app1.js']);
```

using `__dirname` properly, otherwise, PATH context problem occurs especially using shell script.

thanks.